# CSS Positioning elements in a header

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

So I'm trying to create a navigational menu header and it also includes a logo in it, fairly simple but some of the buttons the left side are inline-block with the logo itself and they appear at the bottom of the logo, to the right of it based on ordering, but at the bottom and im not sure how with css to get them to go to the top of the container or if the roof of their container is just lower that I'm thinking?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthService } from './backend/client/auth';
import { Paper, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
container: {
    'height': 128,
},
leftnav: {
    'display': 'inline-block',
},
rightnav: {
    'float': 'right',

},
button: {
    'display': 'inline-block',
}
});


class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.leftnav}>
                <Link to="/" className={classes.button}>
                    <img src="https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Corporation/98523546_128.png" alt="Hole Puncher's Logo"></img>
                </Link>
                <Button component={Link} to="/">
                    Home
                </Button>
                <Button component={Link} to="/store">
                    Browse
                </Button>
                <Button component={Link} to="/contact-us">
                    Contact Us
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.rightnav}>
                {AuthService.isAuthed()
                    ? <Button component={Link} to="/account/orders">Account</Button>
                    : ''}
                {AuthService.isAuthed()
                    ? <Button component={Link} to="/login">Login</Button>
                    : <Button onClick={AuthService.logout} component={Link} to="/login"></Button>}
            </div>
        </Paper>
    )
}
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyZnj.png

Comment: Do you want to align your buttons to the top of the image? Confused about what you are asking in your question.

Comment: Yeah along the top of the screen/where the top of the image is, but not above it, just beside it like that but at the top of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways to solve it using CSS. Simplest way is to use `vertical-align: top` in your `button` class. I would however recommend you look into `display: flex`. It's much easier for vertical alignment.

Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhefbudx/

Hope this helps.